# How do I get the url from a php variable?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, var

I have a php variable that fetches woocommerce product images. It works well and I have tested it. Here it is below ...

```
if( $product instanceof WC_Product ){
  $order_img = $product->get_image( 'full' );
}
```

if I echo `$order_img` the variable returns the image as follows

```
<img width="900" height="1200" src="https://mywebsite.it/.../.../image.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" loading="lazy">
```

**What I am doing**

What I am trying to do is to have the images taken from the variable as a background in a div. So I did this, obviously it doesn't work because instead of getting just the src link I get the img tag as shown above.

```
style='background-image: url("<?php echo wp_kses_post($order_img) ?>");'
```

**So in the html I will have this**

```
style='background-image: url("<img width="900" height="1200" src="https://mywebsite.it/.../.../image.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" loading="lazy">");'
```

**But I would like to achieve this**

```
style='background-image: url("https://mywebsite.it/.../.../image.jpg");'
```

So my question is, how can I just retrieve the link from my variable? Is there any way to do it?

Comment: This question shows a woeful lack of effort.  A simple search for php string functions would have given you a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, I leave below for anyone who is in the same condition as me

I searched a bit on google and found this post https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/338390/get-url-of-products-images-woocommerce So here's how I solved it

I added two more variables to grab the url of the image `$image_id` `$image_url`

```
if( $product instanceof WC_Product ){
  $order_img = $product->get_image( 'full' );
  $image_id  = $product->get_image_id();
  $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, 'full' );
}
```

After that I wrote this

```
style='background-image: url("<?php echo wp_kses_post($image_url) ?>");'
```

and I finally got this in the html

```
style='background-image: url("https://mywebsite.it/.../.../image.jpg");'
```

However I leave the question open without accepting this answer. If there are better ways of doing this, I would be happy to see how you can improve your practice. Thanks to everyone for any answers.

Comment: Use `esc_url` rather than `wp_kses_post`